# How to update a property on another property change in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a `Product` object where I have properties I need to calculate.

```
export class Order {
    ProductId: number;
    Quantity: number;
    Price: number;
    PriceTotal: number;
}
```

When a user select the number of products (`Quantity`) I want to update the `PriceTotal` value eg:

```
this.PriceTotal = this.Quantity * this.Price;
```

Where can I do it so my screen updates `PriceTotal` upon selection/ change of `Quantity` value by user?

Comment: Why not make `PriceTotal` a read-only [*accessor*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors), so you change either `Quantity` or `Price` then the new value is calculated? Storing the product again isn't very DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you...

```js
export class Order {
    ProductId: number;
    Quantity: number;
    Price: number;
    get PriceTotal(){
      return this.Quantity * this.Price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo it compiles but it doesn't update on `Quantity` update eg. I have `this.selectedProduct = new Product();` in my service constructor and `{{ productService.selectedProduct.PriceTotal }}` in my template. So filling in `{{ productService.selectedProduct.Quantity }}` field `{{ productService.selectedProduct.PriceTotal }}` remains 0. `PriceTotal()` gets hit only on creating the `Product` object not on updating its property value

Comment: I meant `this.selectedOrder = new Order();` of course

Comment: Thanks it works, I just initialized wrongly my object before

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I tried to do the same thing and got it using ngOnChange. just observe the changes in the variable and when it occurs change the value of your property.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges